# How to make sure output is same length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know is there a way in python to make sure that the output is the same length , by adding white space or something like that.

```
78364721 apple 3 3 9
35619833 orange 4 2 8
46389121 chicken 1 10 10
total price of order £ 27
```

I want :

```
78364721  apple     3 3 9
35619833  orange    4 2 8
46389121  chicken 1 10 10
total price of order £ 27
```

Current Code :

```
All_list=[items,product_list,items2,indprice_list,newprice_list]
for a in zip(*All_list):
    print(*a)

print("total price of order","£",total_price)


46389121   chicken     2 10 20
total price of order £ 40
46389121   chicken     2 10 20
total price of order £ 40
```

Comment: Yes there is a way. Take a look at [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), including the Format Specification Mini-Language, and the [Format examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: How would I include that in my current code ?

Comment: Most people would use an editor and type the desired code.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example using [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dataframe = [
    [78364721, "apple", 3, 3, 9],
    [35619833, "orange", 4, 2, 8],
    [46389121, "chicken", 1, 10, 10]
]

for row in dataframe:
    print('{:8d}  {:10s}{:3d}{:3d}{:3d}'.format(
        row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))

print('total price of order \u00a3 {0}'.format(
    sum([row[4] for row in dataframe])))
```

If you want anything fancier than this I'd recommend you start using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: this is why i only include the python 3 tag.

Comment: @JEE Oh, I hadn't seen the 3.x tag, I've edited my answer

Comment: I hate people who come here just to edit my tags , like I have only included one for a reason.

Comment: In my code , I do not know what the user input will be it can change , so how do I change the dataframe ?

Comment: @JEE I added the tag for the visibility effect it has on questions, with it way more users actually see your question. I left the `python-3.x` tag specifically in order to let others know about the version you're using. It was BPL's slight mistake for not noticing it here, but he fixed that. :-)

Comment: ok , BPL , the first line works great how ever the second comes out really weird. ( look at edit)

Comment: @JEE I don't know what you mean with `how do I change the dataframe`, so I'll stick to my last answer's comment `If you want anything fancier than this I'd recommend you start using pandas`

Comment: @JEE All Python questions should have the generic `python` tag, they may also have a version-specific tag, when relevant. Leaving out the generic tag means that people who are watching the `python` tag page will not see your question, and it also prevents people who get points answering your question from getting those points credited towards the `python` tag badges.

Comment: I don't see what `pandas` has to do with this. Its great for certain types of matrix problems but has little to do with the general question of formatting output. Not every problem requires a module outside of the standard API.